# Fetch neo4j data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to fetch data from my neo4j database and show them in cards.
Here is my function to fetch the data:

```
 constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

async componentDidMount() {

        const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver')
        const driver = neo4j.driver('bolt://localhost:7687', neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j', 'pass'))
        const session = driver.session({database: 'mydatabase'})
        let result = null
        
        try {

            result = await session.run(
                "MATCH (a:Person { userid: $userID })<-[:`has relation`]-(b:Job)-[:`another relation`]->(c:Person) RETURN b.name AS name, c.job +' '+ c.additional_job AS job",
                {
                    userID: userID
                }
            )

        } catch (error) {
          console.log(`unable to execute query. ${error}`)
        } finally {
            await session.close()
        }
        
         await driver.close()
         this.setState({
             data: result.records
        })

         
    }
```

And this is the render method:

```
render(){

       
        
        return(
         <section>
              <h1>my jobs</h1>
               
             { Object.keys(this.state.data).map((item, index) => <MyCard key={index} name={item.name} job={item.job}/>) }
         </section>   
          
        );
    }
```

But it's showing the following error:

```
TypeError: data.map is not a function
```

Can you tell me what is missing here?

And, currently I am using an asynchronous `function ( async fetchData() )` to fetch data. Should I use `componentDidMount()` function to fetch data from neo4j database?

I get following in the console:

```
 Promise {<pending>}
    [[Prototype]]: Promise
    [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
    [[PromiseResult]]: Array(2)
        0: Record
            keys: (2) ['name', 'job']
            length: 2
            _fieldLookup: {name: 0, job: 1}
            _fields: (2) ['name 1', 'first job another job']
            [[Prototype]]: Object
        1: Record
            keys: (2) ['name', 'job']
            length: 2
            _fieldLookup: {name: 0, job: 1}
            _fields: (2) ['name 2', ' second job another job ']
            [[Prototype]]: Object
            length: 2
            [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Comment: Hey there, it looks like you are trying to map an Object (not an Array). So, if you want to loop through and Object, what you can do is getting values or keys of the object with Object.keys(data) - Object.values(data) and these functions will return Array for you to use map function.

Comment: @Batuhan Isildak
How to create the array from the object?

Comment: @Batuhan Isildak i tried like { [data].map((item, index) => <MyCard key={index} name={item.name} job={item.job}/>) } 
in this case, error disappears, but the MyCard does get any value. Is there any alternative ways to fetch the data ?

Comment: Can you post a sample of data that you are trying to map?

Comment: @Batuhan Isildak

i tried Object.keys(data).map(). 
But it returns no value

Comment: Did u try to use like that: Object.keys(data).map((item, index) => console.log(item)) If this doesn't return anything sensible, maybe you can check your data. (By the way if you could post the data that you are trying to map I can help much more than this, so could you do console.log(data) and share it with me (if the data is not sensitive!!!))

Comment: @Batuhan Isildak

i updated the question with console.log(data)

Comment: { Object.keys(data).map((item, index) => console.log('with object: ', item))} does not return anything on the console

Comment: So, due to your function is async, you should await for your function to finish. This is why the data starts with  Promise {<pending>} and this is why we can't get the data properly. Since you can't use await in the render function, you should await the data to be ready in componentDidMount I guess.

Comment: @Batuhan Isildak

you mean i should use componentDidMount() instead of fetchData() and it should be async ?

Comment: Yeah maybe you can call the fetchData function at componentDidMount and await for it.

Comment: @Batuhan Isildak
please have a look at the updated code. i have used a state data[] which is updated in componentDidMount() function. It is creating 2 cards, but the don't get values of name and job. another problem is it says 'Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'' and 'Property 'job' does not exist on type 'string''

Comment: So instead of item.name and item.job, can you use item[index].name and item[index].job?

Comment: i used { Object.keys(this.state.data).map((item, index) => <MyCard key={index} name={item[index].name} job={item[index].job}/>) }, but it shows same error and creates another error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Comment: Alright, can you console log the each item please

Comment: like this ? { Object.keys(this.state.data).map((item, index) => console.log('with object: ', item))} show - with object:  0 with object:  1

Comment: @Batuhan Isildak
i can't find any clue why data is not loading while creating the cards. you can suggest me any alternative to fetch data and display them accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects, `{}` in JavaScript do not have the method `.map()`. It's only for Arrays, `[]`.

So in order for your code to work change `data.map()` to `data.products.map()` since products is an array which you can iterate upon.

Comment: i tried data.products.map() , but it shows another error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')